# Geeqie in full screen using external second display connected to laptop

Tags: 11.10

It used to work fine under 11.04. I've got thinkpad hooked up with external display via docking station. Laptop is a main display, external LCD is for web browser or for pictures display.

I use geeqie for viewing jpgs, and when I press full screen on any picture it goes to the laptop display instead staying on the external lcd. On ubuntu 11.04 it was working as it should.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

solved, problem was in geeqie settings - all sorted now.

There is an option where you can choose the monitor of where program displays pictures fullscreen.